# Setting Root URL in Ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, client-side

I have an app that's using the ember-rails gem on top of Ruby on Rails.

I have an ember route that is '/projects' that I would like to set at the root URL. I know that it's possible to set this with a redirect like so:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   redirect: function() {
      this.transitionTo('/projects');
    }
});
```

However this means that my root URL is now always 'localhost:3000/projects'.

Is it possible to change the root URL so that it routes to '/projects' but shows the URL as just localhost:3000.

My current router.js is as follows:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto',
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('projects'), { path: '/' };
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('/projects');
  }
});
```

And my Rails routes.rb is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :projects
    end
  end

  root to: 'home#index'

  get '*path', to: 'home#index'
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/#toc_specifying-a-root-url

Answer (score 0):

In the current version `v4.9` you can do

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('projects', { path: '/' });
});
```

in `app/router.js`. This will set the url for "/projects" to "/". You can then additionally add a redirection so that when you go to "localhost:3000/projects" it redirects to the rootURL. You can also do it the otherway around by setting the `rootURL` property in `config/environment.js`.